# how do i move inputs in a div, but using background-coloring extend the divs selection box around the object in css

Tags: jquery, css

I have a **div** which contains some input.  The contents of the divs are variable, but checking with background-color, how do i extend the height and width of the surrounding div to envelop the inputs.

I have my sample at:  http://jsfiddle.net/fallenreaper/pL6Ua/

The goal is that if the widths adjust, then all the boxes will shift down.

I tried things like:

```
position: relative;
```

but it doesnt quite wrap the surrounding div.  What am i missing?

**Edit:**
The javascript is for an expanding tool i am working on.  The item which is being shown on the screen is:

```
$alt_item
```

**Edit2:**  The content of the divs are dynamic, so i need to be able to push everything down to accomidate.  Essentially, it seems like it should look something like: if you set the *$("#dtr_list > div")* height to 80px.

I was thinking to do it with Javascript as an option, find the greatest (height + top) of all children, and then set the height = to that.

**Edit3:**

```
var maxH = 0;
$($("#dtr_list > div")[0]).children().each(function(){
    $("#altdata").append("Top: "+$(this).position().top + " Height: "+ $(this).height()+ "<br />");
    if(($(this).position().top + $(this).height()- $(this).parent().position().top+5) > maxH)
    {
        maxH = $(this).position().top + $(this).height() - $(this).parent().position().top + 5;
    }
});
$("#altdata").append("maxH: "+maxH);
$("#dtr_list > div").css("height", maxH);
```

This javascript will resolve it, but i don't like that i needed to do it programmatically.  That *+5* i added was because of the margin but you can replace +5 as a hardcoded number to something like:

```
Number($(this).parent().css("margin").match(/^\d/))
```

Comment: you need to clear your floats

Comment: should i just do use margin controls to place them on the right of the div?

Comment: have a look at this:  http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: I am not sure that resolves what i am looking at.  Well, floats at least.  Maybe i can apply it to he items with a position determined by LEFT&&Right

Comment: After looking at it, it will wrap it up, but does not expand the height to properly wrap.

Comment: Are you wanting the two inputs to be next to each other and then wrap if the screen is too small, with the height of the div expanding if it wraps?

Comment: the content of the divs, is going to be dynamic at some point, so i want the heigh to expand to wrap around the content, and then due to the height expanding, pushes everything down.

Comment: if you take off your relative positioning and add a clear spacer you get this: http://jsfiddle.net/pL6Ua/2/

Comment: the contents inside the div, will most likely have some sort of positioning elements to it, which is why i was trying to see if the relative position and the left&top variables were injected.  In the case where objects inside the div have those attributes, heights would adjust

Comment: maybe, i would have to use javascript to search all elements for their positions and heights, and then get the one object with the largest height + top value, and set the parent div's height as that.